# Proof the function $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$ is a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ an infinite sequence of random variables such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega)$ exists and it's finite for each $\omega \in \Omega$. Then proof the function $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$ is a random variable.

**UPDATE**

I have this, but I'm not sure if it's in the correct direction.

$B \in Borelians, X_n^{-1}(B) \in \mathscr{F} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n^{-1}(B) \in \mathscr{F}$

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: There is not really a lot of probability here, what you want to prove is that $\lim_{n}X_n$ is a measurable function with the respect to the ambient $\sigma-$albegra.

Comment: @carmichael561 I update it with what I have.

Comment: @clark And How do I prove that?

Comment: It might help to start by showing that $\sup_nX_n$ is a random variable. The infimum works in a similar way, and from there you can get the limsup and liminf.

Comment: And also consider the other definition of measurability: say, for all $a\in\mathbb R$, $\{\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n \leq a\}\in \mathscr{F}$.

Answer (score 5):

Denote the limit $X_{\infty}$

So let us try and see when $X_\infty(\omega) <a$ this happens if and only if 
$$\exists k, \exists N,~ \forall n>N,~ X_n (\omega)<a-\frac{1}{k}$$
So 
$$ [X_\infty <a] = \bigcup_{k\geq1} \bigcup _{N\geq 1} \bigcap_{n>N}[X_n<a-\frac{1}{k}]$$

Each $\exists$ translates to $\cup $ and $\forall$ to $\cap$.